# RemoteApp shows no certificate available but RD Session host finds it fine

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp, digital-signatures

I am trying to set up remote app for a internal domain. I have a Root CA that is trusted my all of the end computers, that cert has signed a wildcard cert I am trying to use for the server.

I added the pfx of the wildcard cert to the local machine personal store. From there I can use it fine for signing the RD Session Host session.

[image]

---

However when I try to set up the signature for Remote App the certificate does not show up.

[image]

---

What do I need to do to get my certificate to be available for for use?

---

**UPDATE:**

The Certificate was generated through the following commands:

```
makecert -pe -n "CN=*.vw.local" -a sha1 -sky signature -ic VetWebCA.cer -iv VetWebCA.pvk -sv VetWebComputerWildcard.pvk VetWebComputerWildcard.cer

pvk2pfx -pvk VetWebComputerWildcard.pvk -spc VetWebComputerWildcard.cer -pfx VetWebComputerWildcard.pfx
```

The resultant pfx was added to the machine local store via mmc.

Oddly, going in to Powershell if I add the `-CodeSigningCert` flag to find the wildcard certificate it is excluded from the serch results for `Get-Childitem` in my `Cert:\Local Machine\My` path, but if I don't include it it is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Remote app requires explicit rights to use it for signing, you can not just use the `<All>` rights. Changing my cert generation to

```
makecert -pe -n "CN=*.vw.local" -a sha1 -sky signature -ic VetWebCA.cer -iv VetWebCA.pvk -sv VetWebComputerWildcard.pvk -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 VetWebComputerWildcard.cer
```

solves the issue (`1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1` & `1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2` are Client Authentication and Server Authentication rights)